# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm making a progress bar for my music react-app. I want to make the progress-indicator to show up whenever the user hover on the progress-bar-container. But I face with this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')

My Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('rhap_progress-container')[0].onmouseover = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('rhap_progress-indicator').style.display = "block";
}
document.getElementsByClassName('rhap_progress-container')[0].onmouseout = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('rhap_progress-indicator').style.display = "none";
}
```

My html:

```
<div class="rhap_progress-container" aria-label="Audio progress control" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="24.67" tabindex="0">
  <div class="rhap_progress-bar ">
    <div class="rhap_progress-indicator" style="left: 24.67%;"></div>
    <div class="rhap_progress-filled" style="width: 24.67%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.rhap_progress-indicator {
  display: none;
  width: 18px !important;
  height: 18px !important;
  border: 3px solid #232530;
  top: -7 px !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  content: url('./img/outlined-progress-indicator.png');
}
```

Comment: Notice when you declare the event handler, you realise its an array and thus affix `[0]` but you don't do this in the event handler itself.

Comment: You missed the index along with the "getElementsByClassName" inside the function block 
Alternatively, you may add an id and go for "getElementById"

document.getElementsByClassName('rhap_progress-indicator')[0].style.display = "block";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array.

So `document.getElementsByClassName('rhap_progress-indicator')` needs to also select an index of the array:

`document.getElementsByClassName('rhap_progress-indicator')[0]`.

The alternative is to use `document.querySelector('.rhap_progress-indicator')`, which returns the element if it exists.

Comment: it showed up another error: Playing.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onmouseover')

Answer (score 1):

you need to select index of node list when you use `getElementsByClassName`

this would work for you:

```js
let Container = document.getElementsByClassName('rhap_progress-container');
let Indicator = document.getElementsByClassName('rhap_progress-indicator');

Container[0].onmouseover = function(){
  Indicator[0].style.display = "block";
}
Container[0].onmouseout = function(){
  Indicator[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Another problem here: Playing.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Comment: @ChimmFX I've edited code, check this one.

Comment: Hey, I dont know how but this work until I refresh the page and the page is blanked (I'm using reactjs to build this so it means it failed to compile). Here is the error message in console log: Playing.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'onmouseover')

Comment: @ChimmFX you didn't define one the `rhap_progress-container` or `rhap_progress-indicator` in your html body

Comment: I used React so the html is automatically written by the react-app not myself, I'm only add more function to it

Comment: @ChimmFX so put this code in `window.onload = function() { // code }`